# Does moving static files out of domain mean out of html directory?

Tags: seo, dns

I want to follow the suggestion of moving static files out of domain. But it's a bit confusing-- Host says html directory is where you put your publicly accessible files. That sounds to me means the static files won't be available for public if I put them out of html dir. Inside the html dir, I can create subdomains or folders. So, where exactly should I put the static files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving static files "out of your domain" probably means putting them on some other domain.  You probably need to ask for clarification from the source of this advice.   Is this supposed to a remedy for a Panda penalty?

### Moving file off the web

Move the files out of your html directory and they will no longer be publicly available.  Users will get 404 not found errors.

### Moving files do a different domain

Put the files in a the html directory of another site.  You would probably want to set up 301 permanent redirects from the old site using .htaccess

### Moving files to a subdomain

Similar to moving to a different domain but your subdomain directory sounds like it would be a subdirectory in your html directory